# C2676 Binary '++': SetIterator<TElement> does not define this operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to define the `operator ++` on my Set iterator to call the method `next()`, so it would increment the position in the iterator.

```
template<typename TElement>
class SetIterator {

private:

    Set<TElement>& set;
    int poz;

public:

    SetIterator(Set<TElement>& set, int poz) : set{ set }, poz{ poz } {
        while (set.elems[this->poz] == EMPTY || set.elems[this->poz] == DELETED)
            this->poz++;
    };

    SetIterator(const SetIterator& other) = default;

    ~SetIterator() = default;

    bool valid() {
        return poz < set.capacity;
    };

    void next() {
        poz++;
        while (set.elems[poz] == EMPTY || set.elems[poz] == DELETED)
            poz++;
    };

    SetIterator<TElement>& operator ++ () {
        next();
        return *this;
    };

    TElement& element() {
        return set.elems[poz];
    };
};
```

The problem is that it doesn't recognize my definition of the operator ++ when i use it:

```
SetIterator<int> it = set.begin();// set.begin() returns an iterator with poz=0
    while (it.valid()) {
        std::cout << it.element() << std::endl;
        it++;
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator you defined is a [prefix operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec), so you should call it like this:

```
++it;
```

If you need the postfix one, declare it as follows:

```
SetIterator<TElement> operator ++ (int);
```